# A question on Automorphism on Galois Theory

Tags: galois-theory, automorphism-group

In one of my references it says, any Automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is determined by its action on generators $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.
Im really confuse why
is the image of $\sqrt{2}$ under $\sigma$ goes only to either $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$.
Same goes for $\sqrt{3}$, goes only to either $\sqrt{3}$ or $-\sqrt{3}$.

any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question turned out to be duplicate of an older one. We have pretty much covered standard questions already on the site. Don't worry about it too much, it takes a while for new users to realize how much ground we have covered already. You'll get the hang of it soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

As a counterexample, if $\sigma(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt 3$, then

$2=\sigma(2)=\sigma(\sqrt 2\sqrt2) = \sigma(\sqrt 2)\sigma(\sqrt 2) = \sqrt 3\sqrt 3  =3$,

as $\sigma$ leaves the base field fixed (eq 1).

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot..